clangでADLを使おうとすると警告されるのはなぜ？
clangでADLを使おうとすると警告されるのはなぜ？
cl /W4 と g++ -Wall では何も指摘されません。
#include    <utility>

int     main()
{
    std::pair<int, int>     x;
    x = move(x);
}

test.cpp:6:9: warning: unqualified call to 'std::move' [-Wunqualified-std-cast-call]
    6 |     x = move(x);
      |         ^
      |         std::
1 warning generated.

clang version 17.0.3
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin


今ちょっと clang が使えない状況なのでアレですが
普通に ADL が発動する状況、例えば endl(std::cout); に対しても clang は警告するのでしょうか？オイラの記憶によれば、このコードに警告は出ないはず。
この件においてなぜの判断をしているのは clang の開発コミュニティです。中の人に直接訊かないかぎりは正しい回答は得られないでしょう。gcc や visual-c++ で警告を出さないほうが良い/出さなくてよいという判断をしているのは同様 gcc 開発コミュニティなり visual-c++ 開発コミュニティですから、出ない理由もやはり中の人に訊かなければならないでしょう。
でもまあ検索して出てきた範囲では
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78953403/ 中のリンク先
https://reviews.llvm.org/D119670?id=408276 がどうもそれっぽいようです。
これによると std::move と std::forward に限り特別に診断を追加している様子。
オイラ流超訳： move も forward もあまりに一般的な名前であること。が故に c++ の名前空間 std:: に属さない move forward がユーザーの作った何か（まあ関数ですわね）でありえて、 clang のユーザーはそれ＝「std:: に属さない move」 を呼んでいるつもりなのに ADL によって std::move 等が意図せず呼び出されるのはあまりうれしくない→警告すべきでは？　という提案に合意があったから、ということのようです。
なので -Wunqualified-std-move と -Wunqualified-std-forward の２つを新設して、この両者を同時に有効化する -Wunqualified-std-call も用意しよう、ってことになったみたいです。
提示サンプルに関しては ADL によらず std::move と書けば警告出ないはず（未試験）
